# ADF/Synapse all Objects iterate and remove the Underscore

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

Wanted to iterate the list of objects/Tables and exclusively for one object which is not getting picked up as there is Underscore between the words "Admin_process" Expectation is to get as "Adminprocess" in the adf/synapse by removing the underscore,such that all objects will be passed to the copy operation.

Objects/Tables list
AdminUser
Admin_process
TempUser

[image]

Currently it is above, However is not reading the object "Admin_Process" as there is underscore.

Could you someone please tell me how to handle this case.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` function in ADF dynamic content.

please follow the demonstration below.

Here I am using an array parameter with keys and the above list of tables as values.

```
[   
{     
"Objectname": "AdminUser"   
},     
{     
"Objectname": "Admin_process"   
},  
{   
"Objectname": "TempUser"    
} 
]
```

[image]

**Parameter array to ForEach activity:**

[image]

To use replace function, create a set variable activity and give the below expression.

```
@replace(item().Objectname, '_','' )
```

[image]

Output with required result(**Underscore removed**):

[image]

Now you can pass this value to a copy activity inside the same ForEach activity.

Comment: I cannot pass them as a array as there are many objects to iterate actually.

Comment: @Never_Give_Up, In the above I have used the array parameter only for a sample. You can get that list from Get Meta data activity **childItems** like this step1-https://i.imgur.com/y9fmTRm.png and step2- https://i.imgur.com/zV7432b.png. You can use this list in ForEach as `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` and can access your table name as `@item().name` inside ForEach.